# asp.net checkbox and html checkbox

Tags: asp.net, html, checkbox

There is one html checkbox whose id is"notice". in the code behind file i hv to use it.How should i declare it ?i hv written this but it is showing error that notice does not exist in the current context.

notifying = ((notice.Checked) ? 1 : 0);

when i m using asp.net checkbox it is not showing any errror. why?
Also, I hv written one jquery function which is working fine with html checkbox but not working with asp.net checkbox. where is the problem.where i m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `runat="server"`?

```
<input id="notice" type="checkbox" name="notice" runat="server" />
```

Comment: in addition to that. Your jquery function will need to reference the control try putting this where you would put the id of your check box.. <%= notice.ClientID %>

Answer (score 0):

> There is one html checkbox whose id is"notice". in the code behind file i hv to use it.Blockquote

Make sure that any "html" controls you need to address at the server have a

```
runat="server"
```

inside of them.  a la:

```
<input id="notice" type="checkbox" runat="server" />
```